# What is "numerically exact approach"?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, numerical-calculus

I read a paper now (field: theoretical physics, which is also my background), where they claim that some approach to solve the problem is "numerically exact".

What does this mean?

Comment: We will need the paper to answer this. It is not a standard term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the algorithm used to solve the problem does not involve any approximation so that the final result is exact up to machine precision ($10^{-16}$ for double precision floats for example).

Comment: But isn't then this an analytical solution? What is the difference?

Comment: I would use the term "numerically exact" for example when the computation involves a numerical diagonalization of a matrix (to determine the energy spectrum of an Hamiltonian or to compute a partition function by diagonalizing the transfer matrix). I would reserve the term "analytical solution" to situations where a mathematical expression is given.